# How to get an input set to display block to fade in with css

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein

I am stuck and have looked all over for a solution for this. On page load I have my inputs `opacity: 0` and then full opacity later, but I need the inputs to display as block in order for them to go down the page instead of inline. Doing this is counteracting the fade in I have with the `.block` class. Is there anyway I can get the inputs to be in a block fashion and still fade in with css?

Also, is there a way in my example to get the labels/inputs to display block so that the label is over the input and they are centered on the page?

[This fiddle demonstrates it best](https://jsfiddle.net/xfbLskhn/3/)

```js
$(function() {
  var elems = $('.intro input').on('keypress', function() {

    if ($(this).val().trim().length > 2) {
      $(this).parent().next('label').addClass('block');
    }


    $('#intro-button').toggle(
      elems.filter(function() {
        return this.value.trim() !== "";
      }).length === elems.length
    )

  });
});
```

```css
.intro {
 opacity: 0;
}
.info-input {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 margin: 40px auto;
}
.intro:first-child {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
}
.block {
 display: block;
 visability: visible;
 opacity: 1;
   -webkit-animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
   -moz-animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
    animation: fadein 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="intro">What is your name?
    <input id="name" type="text" class="info-input">
   </label>
   <label class="intro">What is your email address?
    <input id="email" type="email" class="info-input">
   </label> 
   <label class="intro">What is your title?
    <input id="title" type="text" class="info-input">
   </label>
```

Comment: to display your labels as `block`, you don't need to wrap your input field within a `label`, just use `for="#id"` attribute and that's it, where `#id` represent the `id` of the relative input field, like this [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/xfbLskhn/5/)

Comment: this is the final functional [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/60vauuk2/2/)

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Thanks, this is perfect! Feel free to leave an answer

Comment: You welcome and I'm glad it helped, this wasn't an answer I just modified @WillBraden answer, enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "animation" to "transition" on ".block"

```
    .block {
      display: block;
      visability: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/willbraden/60vauuk2/)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can get the label/input to appear in a block formation? The label over the input. Everything I try makes all of the inputs show on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Can do with the the animation prop in CSS. Something like this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.your-div {
  display: none;
}
.your-div.show {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fade-in 0.2s;
  -moz-animation: fade-in 0.2s;
  -o-animation: fade-in 0.2s;
  animation: fade-in 0.2s;
}
```