# jQuery input focus css animation

Tags: jquery, css

As soon as I click inside the input, I want my border colors to come in animated form and fade out with the same animation after exiting the input, but I'm stuck somewhere.

Following my code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search..">
```

**CSS**

```
#search-input{
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  font-size:16px;
}
#search-input:focus{
  outline:none
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('#search-input').on('focus',function(){
  jQuery(this).css('border', '2px solid #f27a1a','transition', '0.2s');
}).on('focusout',function(){
  jQuery(this).css('border','2px solid transparent','transition', '0.2s');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/justfeel/t7kb8hea/4/

Comment: there isn't any animation in your code......

Comment: yes i want to know how to do it

Comment: Before asking we expect you make some search on Google or SO. I'm sure you can find a lot of example.

Comment: Try look at this, no need for jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299680/add-animation-to-border-bottom-on-input

Comment: Add the `transition:2s;` to the css: https://jsfiddle.net/yfeq3L5t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that there is no `.css` overload that takes multiple arguments as "pairs"

```
$(this).css('border', '2px solid #f27a1a','transition', '0.2s');
```

In the general case, you can split this into two calls

```
$(this)
    .css('border', '2px solid #f27a1a')
    .css('transition', '0.2s');
```

or use one of the overloads that allows multiple arguments

```
  $(this)
    .css({
       'border': '2px solid transparent',
       'transition': '0.2s'
    });
```

---

In the *specific* case for this question:  add the transition in the css so there's no need to add it (as the same value) on focus in/out.

```
#search-input{
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  font-size:16px;
  transition:0.2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857642/how-to-get-an-input-set-to-display-block-to-fade-in-with-css) with same requirement. you can customize with your own requirement